# Super trivial postgreSQL question (alias)

Tags: sql, postgresql, table-alias

This is what I did

```
select f.visits 
from pls_fy2014_pupld14a pfpa as f
```

and I got:

**SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS"**

This case below is working but I don't get why I cannot use 'as'

```
select visits 
from pls_fy2014_pupld14a pfpa
```

Comment: is pfpa suppose to be the alias?

Answer (score 1):

Aliases always have to be put directly after the table or column name, so in your case:

```
SELECT pfpa.visits AS f
FROM pls_fy2014_pupld14a pfpa
```

Answer (score 1):

In your second query:

```
select visits
from pls_fy2014_pupld14a pfpa;
```

the `pfpa` appearing after the table name is an *alias*.  Note that we can only alias a table once in SQL.  In your second query:

```sql
select f.visits
from pls_fy2014_pupld14a pfpa as f
```

you attempting to alias `pfpa` a second time as `f`.  You can't do that.

Answer (score 0):

You are - probably - trying to alias the table twice. AS is not mandatory, so

```
SELECT pfpa.visits
FROM pls_fy2014_pupld14a pfpa
```

is the same as:

```
SELECT pfpa.visits
FROM pls_fy2014_pupld14a AS pfpa
```

You can not add another alias f